# Scallops purchased in super market

Tags: scallops

I have tried making scallops at home from the super market..They have so much water retained they never seem to be able to be seared correctly.. How do you correct for this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe salting them like you would eggplant would help draw out some moisture.